# Grails with ExtJS or Vaadin?

Tags: grails, extjs4, vaadin

I want to use Grails as the backend of an enterprise web app, but don't know what is the best options for the UI: ExtJS 4 or Vaadin.

- Which one works better with Grails?

They both have great widgets and I think that both will do for what I need. I just need to know which one is the best option to integrate with Grails framework.

Comment: [Vaadin](http://grails.org/plugins/search?q=vaadin) and [ExtJS resource](http://grails.org/plugin/extjs4) plugins for Grails are available. You can have a look and decide which one could be a good choice as long as integration with the grails app is concerned.

Comment: Here is how to start with Vaadin and Grails: http://vaadinongrails.com . We have build few application in Vaadin on Grails, so that would be also my recommendation.

Comment: Thanks. But, is there any limitations, know problems, ..., with any of them?

Comment: I am not aware of know limitations or problems with Vaadin in Grails. Not sure about ExtJS because I didn't work with that...

Answer (score 0):

I used extJS (and yahoo YUI2) before on real project, I have below hints maybe helpful on your chosen:
1, vaadin7 is totally free but that's not the case of extJS.
2, with vaadin7 integration you do not need to write GSPs and Controllers(please refer to vaadinongrails.com for more detail), how ever depends on your own discrimination this is advantage or in contrary

currently I'm evaluating vaadin grails plugin on a real project.